# Distribution Function for Random Variables that take values in a set that is not $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

While doing an exercise on the classic Monkey Typing Shakespeare, I am considering the i.i.d. variables $(X_n)$ which correspond to the $n$-th symbol that the monkey types, from some set of symbols. We assume that $$\varepsilon := \inf\left\{P(X_1 = x) : x\text{ is a symbol}\right\} > 0$$
and the first step is to show that $P(\text{Shakespeare's works are typed in the first block of symbols}) \geq \varepsilon^N$
where $N$ is the length of Shakespeare's works. Naturally if we suppose those first $N$ symbols of Shakespeare's works correspond to symbols $x_1,\dots, x_N$ then this corresponds to the simultaneous occurrence of $X_1 = x_1,\dots, X_N = x_N$, which can be written as a product of probabilities by independence.

Now what I want to use the identical distributions to say that these are all equal to $P(X_1 = x_i)$ for $i=1,\dots, N$ but I am not sure that this is justified: I've seen the definition of distribution function being $P(X \leq x)$ but in this case our $X_n$ take symbols as values, so what is the meaning of identically distributed for these variables?

Comment: For discrete distributions, identically distributed means all probabilities are equal.   The items don't have to be numbers.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Thank you that clears everything up.

Comment: Simplest example: coin flips $P(heads)=P(tails)=1/2$.